# Using User Access Token to create repository via Github API

Tags: python, authentication, github, token, github-app

I am trying to find a way to create a repository via User Access Token (UAT). I have tried with Personal Access Token (PAT) and it was successful. But now I need to use UAT to do it through Github API.

Is it possible to do that ? Thanks in advance.

I asked the question related to Github Apps and want to know the possibility of the answer.